# pytorch albumentations augmentation p value?

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchvision, albumentations

```
augmented_images(raw.image_id.unique()[1230], albumentations.HorizontalFlip(p=1))
```

for augmented_image what is the p=1 mean? is value difference make angle different?
if its not it how should I make various angle different horizontal augmentation?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the docs of [`albumentations.HorizontalFlip`](https://albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/augmentations.html#albumentations.augmentations.transforms.HorizontalFlip):

> **Parameters**:   p (float) – probability of applying the transform. Default: 0.5.

If you want to rotate, you should consider using [`albumentations.augmentations.transforms.Rotate`](https://albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/augmentations.html#albumentations.augmentations.transforms.Rotate):

> `Rotate(limit=90, interpolation=1, border_mode=4, value=None, mask_value=None, always_apply=False, p=0.5)`
>
> Rotate the input by an angle selected randomly from the uniform distribution.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - limit ((int, int) or int) – range from which a random angle is picked. If limit is a single int an angle is picked from (-limit, limit). Default: (-90, 90)
> - [...]
> - p (float) – probability of applying the transform. Default: 0.5.